# JSSOR plugin scrollbar

Tags: jssor

Is there a way to add the scrollbar to vertical image list in this [JSSOR demo](http://www.jssor.com/premium/image-gallery-with-vertical-thumbnail.slider)?

Instead of having the functionality of "drag and scroll", it would be useful if we would have a scrollbar indicating the number of images in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the mark-up of the example slider:

you need to change the following style for `<div class="jssort01-99-66">`:

```
style="width:250px; overflow-y:scroll;"
```

now you have a scroll bar on the right of your thumbs

Comment: This works just visually, unfortunately. The drag and drop from JSSOR still remain on the list, making the scrollbar not that useful, since it is always the same height, ignoring the content completely because the JSSOR generates it's own divs that seem to interfere with the scrollbar.

Comment: what do you mean with works just visually? you might need to add the css style after the slider has loaded, with jquery

Comment: For example: you have 16 items that are shown in the list, 12 is the maximum visible in the list section. When adding scrollbar, the rest of the 4 items are not visible by the when scrolling, because the bar locks at 12, but instead only the drag scroll works. I think the issue here is how JSSOR generates HTML for the list.